# How to format output file at the command line?

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I'm using grep to retrieve all logs after a time stamp on a log file.

```
grep -A 100 "2013/02/13 19*" log.out > newfile.txt
```

Is there a way to format it at the command line so the text file's new lines start at a specific text? For example, I want "info" to start at a new line.

Comment: You are going to have to elaborate a little bit.  What does the output look like now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed to remove \r and \n characters from the output of grep, then use sed to replace "specific text" with "specific text\n" characters. It should work I suppose.

Comment: I tried _sed -i "s/INFO/INFO\n/g" newfile.txt_ but when I open newfile.txt in Windows, it still looks unformatted.

Comment: Either use notepad++ or if you want to see newlines in notepad in windows, use \r\n instead of only \n